# Custom function with PyQt4 and Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, qt4, pyqt4

How to define custom function within QtSql.QSqlDatabase?

Within pure python ([python - sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function)), it seem easy but i don't undestand how to do it within PyQt.

Answer (score 0):

My first question was about registering a function regexp to filter data in QSqlTableModel.
I dunno if it's possible to register our own function like in regular python sqlite3, but anyway to solve my problem i use the Qt way using QSortFilterProxyModel.

In the end we have:

view -> proxy -> model

- [QSortFilterProxyModel Class Reference](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qsortfilterproxymodel.html)

---

```
    tbl = self.tableViewPlaylist
    proxy = self.mediasModelProxy
    proxy.setSourceModel(self.mediasModel)
    proxy.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
    proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(-1)
    tbl.setModel(self.mediasModelProxy)
```

---

```
    def update_filter(self):
        log.info('Updating Filter')
        tokens = str(self.lineEditFilter.text()).split()
        if len(tokens) <= 0:
            self.mediasModelProxy.setFilterRegExp(QRegExp(''))
            return
        nq = '|'.join(tokens)
        rx = QRegExp("(%s)" % nq, Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.mediasModelProxy.setFilterRegExp(rx)
        return
```